# Manusmriti: Legal Guide or Sacred Text?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, manu-smriti, itihasa

I’ve heard discussions about the Manusmriti not being considered a religious text for Hindus. Some claim that it was just made out to be a Hindu legal document by colonial British authorities, and was never used as a legal code in ancient Indian empires. Is the Manusmriti actually a Hindu religious book? Which traditional (Orthodox) Sampradayas (traditions) accept it as such, and which do not? Additionally, are there any references to the Manusmriti in other ancient texts like the Vedas, Itihasas, or Puranas? Also, if we are to rule out the possibility of Manusmriti being a religious text, which other text that is religious in nature could be used as Hindu Legal Code?

Comment: Read visudh manusmriti

Comment: all veda based sampradayas accept manu smriti as a religious text as it is referenced by vedas, puranas, etc. However Manusmriti or any other smriti is not an independent text to be applied as a legal code. Thus for using it to govern a state, the king has to be an initiated kshatriya & educated in vedas, etc. and the state religion has to be vedic religion. British using it is invalid as british were not  initiated kshatriya educated in vedas.